# Is there a faster way to solve the following problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

A is a m*n matrix 

B is a n*n matrix

I want to return matrix C of size m*n such that: 
[image: $C_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} max(0, a_{ij} - b_{jk}) $]

In python it could  be like below

```
for i in range(m):
   for j in range(n):
      C[i][j] = 0
      for k in range(n):
         C[i][j] += max(0, A[i][j] - B[j][k])
```

this runs on O(m*n^2)

if `A[i][j] - B[j][k]` is always > 0 it could easily be improved as

```
C[i][j] = n*A[i][j] - sum(B[j])
```

but it is possible to improve as well when there are cases of `A[i][j] - B[j][k]< 0` ? I think some divide and conquer algorithms might help here but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: You can vectorize your calculation to make it faster, but don't you have to compare all combinations of values anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look on much simpler construct and go from there..

lets say the max between 0 and the addition wasn't there.

so the answer would be : a(i,j)*n - sum(b(j,)
on this you could just go linearly by sum each vector and erase it from a(i,j)*n
and because you need sum each vector in b only once per j it can be done in max(m*n,n*n)

now think about simple solution for the max problem...
if you would find which elements in b(j,) is bigger than a(i,j) you could just ignore their sum and substract their count from the multipication of a(i,j)

All of that can be done by ordering the vector b(j,) by size and make a summing array to each vector from the biggest to lowest (it can be done in n*n*log(n) because you order each  b(j,) vector once)

then you only need to binary search where is the a(i,j) in the ordered vector and take the sum you already found and subtract it from a(i,j) * the position you found in the binary search.

Eventually you'll get O( max( m*n*log(n),n*n*log(n) ) )

I got for you also the implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
M = 4
N = 7
array = np.random.randint(100, size=(M,N))
array2 = np.random.randint(100, size=(N,N))
def matrixMacossoOperation(a,b, N, M):
    cSlow  = np.empty((M,N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            cSlow[i][j] = 0
            for k in range(N):
                cSlow[i][j] += max(0, a[i][j] - b[j][k])
    for i in range(N):
        b[i].sort()
    sumArr = np.copy(b)
    for j in range(N):
        for i in range(N - 1):
            sumArr[j][i + 1] += sumArr[j][i]
    c = np.empty((M,N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            sumIndex = np.searchsorted(b[j],a[i][j])
            if sumIndex == 0:
                c[i][j] = 0;
            else:
                c[i][j] = ((sumIndex) * a[i][j]) - sumArr[j][sumIndex - 1]
    print(c)
    assert(np.array_equal(cSlow,c))
matrixMacossoOperation(array,array2,N,M)
```

Comment: shouldnt that lead to O(m*(n^2)logn)? because sorting has a time O(logn and it will be done m*n times)

Comment: No, I you sort each vector in b(j,) only once, and you have n vectors like that and each vector is in size n -> O(n * n*log(n)). you can use the same b(j,) sorted vector to all c(,j) vector

Answer (score 3):

For each `j`, You can sort each column `B[j][:]` and compute cumulative sums.

Then for a given `A[i][j]` you can find the sum of `B[j][k]` that are larger than `A[i][j]` in O(log n) time using binary search. If there's `x` elements of `B[j][:]` that are greater than `A[i][j]` and their sum is S, then `C[i][j] = A[i][j] * x - S`.

This gives you an overall O((m+n)n log n) time algorithm.

Comment: Had the exact same idea, great minds think alike.

Comment: shouldnt that lead to O(m*(n^2)logn)? because sorting has a time O(logn and it will be done m*n times)

Comment: No, because you can sort and cumulative-sum each column of `B` once and reuse it `n` times.